# shutdown or reboot after entering wrong password x times

Tags: password, security, lightdm, pam

My laptop is configured with a bios password to unlock the encrypted ssd. Most times I don't shut it down and use just suspend/resume - this of course leaves the ssd accessible.

To increase security I want to configure lightdm to automatically shutdown or reboot the machine after entering a wrong password for the third time. Then the user needs to enter the bios password to unlock SSD.

How can this be setup? I have not seed a config option for this in lightdm. Maybe this can be done in PAM?

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: I'd generally recommend against storage encryption handled by the firmware. You never really know if the encryption protocol actually stores your data safely because the firmware is closed source and on-device encryption has a long history of failures.

Comment: Maybe this [answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511503/how-to-configure-a-shutdown-at-the-xth-wrong-entered-password) will help you. I haven't tested it yet, though.